# How to transform a column value into new columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is similar to:

```
accident_type      office A    office B   office C    information      
1                   0          0         0           number        
1                   0          2         2           fatality        
1                   0          0         0           frequency      
2                   0          0         1           number          
2                   0          0         1           fatality        
2                   0          0         0           frequency 
3                   0          0         0           number   
3                   0          1         1           fatality  
3                   0          0         0           frequency
```

and I want to add more column to shift the value of the accident information vertically and later on I will drop office A, office B, office C column and put them into another new column like as follows:

```
accident_type      information         office       number       fatality    frequency     
1                  number              office A        0            0           0
1                  fatality            office B        0            2           0
1                  frequency           office C        0            2           0
2                  number              office A        0            0           0
2                  fatality            office B        0            0           0
2                  frequency           office C        1            1           0 
3                  number              office A        0            0           0 
3                  fatality            office B        0            1           0
3                  frequency           office C        0            1           0
```

I try df.melt but it does not give me my expected result.
Can anyone help me on how can I make it in python?

Thankyou

Comment: What happens to the two `2`s in the office columns for fatality of accident type 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df = (df.melt(['accident_type','information'], 
             var_name='office')
      .pivot_table(index=['accident_type','office'], 
                   columns='information',
                   values='value', 
                   fill_value=0, 
                   aggfunc='sum')
      .reset_index()
      .rename_axis(None, axis=1))
print (df)
   accident_type    office  fatality  frequency  number
0              1  office A         0          0       0
1              1  office B         2          0       0
2              1  office C         2          0       0
3              2  office A         0          0       0
4              2  office B         0          0       0
5              2  office C         1          0       1
6              3  office A         0          0       0
7              3  office B         1          0       0
8              3  office C         1          0       0
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you want to melt, and then pivot on different feature?

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['accident_type', 'information'], var_name='office')
```

will unpivot your columns, but if you need number, fatality and frequency as seperate columns, you need to re-pivot.

```
df = df.pivot_table(index=['accident_type', 'information'], columns='office', values='value')
```

and if you want this as a regular dataframe (not layered):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(df.to_records())
```

(bear in mind that your second pivot is a summary table- if you have unique identifiers, you may want to use pandas 'df.pivot' instead)